# Does citrix excel use local system resources

Tags: citrix

Maybe a silly question, but google searching led me to no definitive answer.  In short, if i am remoted into a citrix environment and running Excel from citrix, is Excel using my local PC's ram/cpu?

Answer (score 0):

Unless Citrix works in very strange ways the answer is going to be no.
Excel doesn't have to be installed on your local machine and there's no easy way to make your computer provide resources to the remote system.